# Bash loop trough all users to delete password hints

Tags: bash, shell

I have newly started with bash and now I am facing the following problem:

```
lukas@Lukass-MacBook-Pro Desktop % ./script.sh
delete: Invalid Path
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14009 (eDSUnknownNodeName)
```

I want to remove all password hints from the users. Can anyone help me here?

```
#!/bin/sh

for user in "$(ls /Users/)"; 
do /usr/bin/dscl . -delete /Users/$user hint
done
```

Comment: `/user/bin/dscl` doesn't exist. It should be `/usr/bin/dscl`...

Comment: `command -v dscl` can help locate it

Comment: @fireshadow52 Yeah that was the wrong path. But with the new one I get following error:       `delete: Invalid Path
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14009 (eDSUnknownNodeName)`

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of issues in your bash script as per [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

> **Line 3**: `for user in "$(ls /Users/)"`;
> ^-- SC2066 (error): Since you
> double quoted this, it will not word split, and the loop will only run
> once.
>
> **Line 4**: `do /usr/bin/dscl . -delete /Users/$user hint`
> ^-- SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

This should do it:

```
#!/bin/sh

for userhomedir in /Users/*/
do /usr/bin/dscl . -delete "$userhomedir" hint
done
```